# SQL: Empty record?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using a sample table(image attached), Working on a SQL query that lists all states with an avg_math_4_score less than the average over all states in the year 2000. Image attached

Using the ff. code, I seem to get an empty record. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT state as below_average_states_y2000, avg_math_4_score
FROM naep
WHERE year = '2000'
GROUP BY avg_math_4_score, state
HAVING avg_math_4_score < AVG(avg_math_4_score)
```

[image: Table Sample]

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by avg_math_4_score and state and each row contains exactly the avg_math_4_score for each state.
Thus, AVG(avg_math_4_score) is always equal to avg_math_4_score and the HAVING condition is never true.

You are probably thinking about something like this:

```
SELECT state as below_average_states_y2000, avg_math_4_score
FROM naep
WHERE year = '2000' and avg_math_4_score<(select avg(avg_math_4_score) from naep where year='2000')
```

BUT mind you, taking average of average is totally wrong in any statistics.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Thank you! I was more specifically trying to get a list of lowest averaged from a list of average.